# Not getting complete bundle while fragment change

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Hi I am trying to create ola/uber sort app.
I am typing some text in the edit-text and based on that Place API is called and array of suggestion is formed. That array is formed using array of the class given below.

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class SearchListProvider implements Serializable {
    private int imageId;
    private String name;
    private Place place;

    public SearchListProvider(int imageId, String name, Place place) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.name = name;
        this.place = place;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }


    public Place getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public void setPlace(Place place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    public void setImageId(int imageId) {

        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

And the part of my adapter is given below where I attach all values with the drop-down.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    SearchListProvider listProvider = null;
    if(holder.viewtype == TYPE_LIST){
        listProvider= arrayList.get(position);
        holder.list_image.setImageResource(listProvider.getImageId());
        holder.address_name.setText(listProvider.getName());
        (holder.itemView).setTag(listProvider);
    }
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment f= new AmbulanceMap();
            Bundle b= new Bundle();
            SearchListProvider p= (SearchListProvider) (v).getTag();
            b.putSerializable("selectedLocation",  p);
            f.setArguments(b);
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container, f).commit();
        }
    });
}
```

Everything is working well till here. Now As I click any of the item in drop-down the fragment changes and I send the serialize object to another fragment and where I try to get it. But what happens there is I get only the half of data.

```
Bundle b= getArguments();
    if(b != null){
        SearchListProvider p= (SearchListProvider)b.getSerializable("selectedLocation");
        if(p != null){
            LatLng latLng= p.getPlace().getLatLng();
            //setCurrentLocationMarker(latLng);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), latLng.latitude + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

On debugging I found that value of place is null.
I am not getting why?
Can anyone help me out?

**NB: getTag() function is itself giving null value of place.**

Now I tried to evaluate the function

```
p.getPlace().getName()
```

and I am getting error as

```
    Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' exception.
    cause = Object has been collected
detailMessage = Object has been collected
stackState = Object has been collected
stackTrace = Object has been collected
```

**new Edit- this functions takes placeId and return place**

```
protected ArrayList<SearchListProvider> doInBackground(String... params) {
    String inputText= params[0];
    PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> autocompletePredictions = geoDataApi.
            getAutocompletePredictions(GoogleClient.getIstance(), inputText, null, null);
    AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictionBuffer = autocompletePredictions.await();
    ArrayList<SearchListProvider> searchList= new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<autocompletePredictionBuffer.getCount(); i++){

        geoDataApi.getPlaceById(GoogleClient.getIstance(), autocompletePredictionBuffer.get(i).getPlaceId()).setResultCallback(new ResolvingResultCallbacks<PlaceBuffer>(fragmentActivity, 0) {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
                p = places.get(0);
                places.release();
            }

            @Override
            public void onUnresolvableFailure(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status status) {

            }
        });
        searchList.add(
                new SearchListProvider(
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                        autocompletePredictionBuffer.get(i).getFullText(null).toString(),
                        p)
        );
    }
    return searchList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment f= new AmbulanceMap();
        Bundle b= new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable("selectedLocation",  listProvider);
        f.setArguments(b);
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container, f).commit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Earlier I was trying that only but then also same error.

Comment: Why don't you try to pass listProvider directly?

Comment: In what form should I pass. give example if possible

Comment: Ok. Try to add a log for place in you onClick method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `SearchListProvider` class implements `Serializable` but the `Place` object doesn't implement `Serializable` that is why the place object doesn't get serialized and hence is null.

Now you can work around this by adding only required fields from place object to your `SearchListProvider` object.

Try this callback for your autocomplete prediction list

```
private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback
            = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                // Request did not complete successfully
                places.release();
                return;
            }
            // Get the Place object from the buffer.
            final Place place = places.get(0);
            lat = place.getLatLng().latitude;
            lng = place.getLatLng().longitude;

            places.release();
        }
};
```

And use it like:

```
locationAutoComplete.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        locationAutoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                final AutocompletePrediction item = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                if (item != null) {
                    final CharSequence primaryText = item.getFullText(null);
                    locationAutoComplete.setText(primaryText);
                    final String placeId = item.getPlaceId();


                    PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                            .getPlaceById(client, placeId);
                    placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: If I dont put serializable then i cannot pass the object.

Comment: If you just want latlng object from places you can implement parcelable because latLng object implements parcelable and u can simply do putParcelable()

Comment: If I say you that place object is not giving anything then. check the edit

Comment: I mean to say as soon as I get place using place Id, place variable doesnot give anything